TypeError: new(): invalid data type 'str' when creating PyTorch Geometric Data object
labeled_X and unlabeled_X are node features (that is gene/protein expressions) matrices for the annotated reference dataset and target unannotated dataset, respectively. They should be numpy arrays with shape [num_nodes, num_node_features] (that is [num_cells, num_genes]).
labeled_y defines annotations for the annotated reference dataset. It is a numpy array with shape [num_nodes,] (that is [num_cells]). Annotations are expected to be numerical class categories.
Question:
I'm trying to create a custom dataset for a graph neural network using PyTorch Geometric's InMemoryDataset. However, I encounter the error TypeError: new(): invalid data type 'str' when creating a Data object. Below is my dataset class and the traceback:
Code:
class GraphDataset(InMemoryDataset):
    def __init__(self, labeled_X, labeled_y, unlabeled_X, labeled_edges, unlabeled_edges, transform=None,):
        self.root = '.'
        super(GraphDataset, self).__init__(self.root, transform)
        self.labeled_data = Data(x=torch.FloatTensor(labeled_X), edge_index=torch.LongTensor(labeled_edges).T, y=torch.LongTensor(labeled_y))
        self.unlabeled_data = Data(x=torch.FloatTensor(unlabeled_X), edge_index=torch.LongTensor(unlabeled_edges).T)
    def __len__(self):
        return 2
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.labeled_data, self.unlabeled_data

Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/scg/apps/software/stellar/13c81ad/stellar/STELLAR_run_yan.py", line 51, in <module>
    main()
  File "/scg/apps/software/stellar/13c81ad/stellar/STELLAR_run_yan.py", line 44, in main
    dataset = GraphDataset(labeled_X, labeled_y, unlabeled_X, labeled_edges, unlabeled_edges)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/scg/apps/software/stellar/13c81ad/stellar/datasets.py", line 84, in __init__
    self.labeled_data = Data(x=torch.FloatTensor(labeled_X), edge_index=torch.LongTensor(labeled_edges).T, y=torch.LongTensor(labeled_y))
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: new(): invalid data type 'str'

Input:
labeled_X
array([[0.05318533, 0.10899889, 0.06755578],
       [0.06478137, 0.08745035, 0.09479886],
       [0.11840215, 0.06308291, 0.07728422],
       [0.09797833, 0.09564686, 0.05342986],
       [0.11716319, 0.13197362, 0.07772677]])

labeled_X.dtype
dtype('float64')

labeled_y
array([0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1])

labeled_y.dtype
dtype('int64')


While you checked the data type, the problem must originate from some string in labeled_X, maybe put a print function right before the problematic call or wrap it in try ... except: breakpoint() and look at the variables that caused the exception one by one in the except block.
